# How to change default output file of g++?

Tags: c++, g++

Trivially

```
g++ sample.c
```

generates `a.out`

Can g++ be configured to output to a different default name for output file ?

Comment: All Unix like systems have what is called manual pages. You can read them by typing `man <command>` in this case `man g++`. Some modern versions also have the slightly more complex but also more complete information systems types `info <command>` or `info g++`

Comment: I think the question here is asking if it's possible to change the default name not change the name on a case by case basis. So if I understand the question correctly, all of the answers below are incorrect. I actually came here looking for a way to change the default name, I know full well how the -o switch works as I suspect @Nullpoet does as well.

Comment: See [Can I configure gcc to always output to the code file's name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283077).

Answer (score 58):

You need to use the `-o` option of [`g++`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)

```
g++ -o output_file_name  source.cpp
```

Comment: I think the pertinent word in the asker's question was 'default', i.e. where is it actually defined that a.out is the default setting when -o is not used, and how can you redefine a new default?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `g++` -o switch: `g++ sample.cc -o myoutfile`

See a [man page for g++](http://parter.kaist.ac.kr/man/g++.html)

> -o file
>   Place output in file file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the default output name to `test` for example, all you need to do is go to .bashrc, and put in:

```
alias g++='g++ -o test'
```

But you need to reopen a new terminal for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Man pages are your friends:
`$ man g++` (and just do a search for "out" and you're done ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile mutiple files at a time:

`g++ -o file_name source1.cpp source2.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

If it’s for a specific project I’d recommend using `make` to do this, you can then define the name of the output file in the Makefile.

Perhaps this is helpful: https://makefiletutorial.com/